# Using models at a project level

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

I know that this question has been posted a few times in different variations but I'm not satisfied with the answers I found so I will explain you my problem, which I think will be easily solved by someone used to Django.

So, I'm a beginner with Django and my problem is that I'm building a food delivery website and I have lots of models such as User, Meal, Order, ... that will be used in all the applications of my project. But, from my very little experience with Django, I understand that the models are defined at an app level, not at a project level. How can I deal with that ? I tried defining some models in an app and importing them in the other apps but I doesn't work : for example, I defined my Client model in the registering app, and my Order model in the ordering app. But when I write "from registering.models import Client" in the Order.models file in order to have a foreign key between Order and Client I have an error saying that it can't find a model Client in the ordering app.

I believe there is some way to define the models at a project level and not at an app level since it would make everybody's life so much easier but I can't find it, can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : here is the error I have :
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHkTt.png)

The name of the apps and models are in french so I give you a litte explanation : I have two apps, actualites (where the models Commande and Plat are defined) and inscription (where the models User, Client, Chef and Entreprise are defined). Plat and Commande have foreign keys pointing towards Chef and Entreprise. 
To resolve the error, in the actualites.models file I write "from inscription.models import Client, Chef, Entreprise" and in the inscription.models file I write "from actualites.models import Plat, Commande" but this gives me the following error :

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JRLy.png)

EDIT2 : 
Code for inscription.models :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#from actualites.models import Plat, Commande

class Chef(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    dateNaissance = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de naissance")
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length = 20, verbose_name = "Numéro de téléphone")
    biographie = models.TextField()
    region = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    photo_profil = models.ImageField(upload_to = "photos/", verbose_name = "Photo de profil")
    nb_plats = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre de plats déjà cuisinés", blank = True)
    rating = models.FloatField(verbose_name = "Notation", blank = True)
    nb_avis = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre d'avis", blank = True)
    account = models.CharField(max_length = 20, verbose_name = "Compte bancaire")

class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    dateNaissance = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de naissance")
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    tel = models.CharField(max_length = 20, verbose_name = "Numéro de téléphone")
    photo_profil = models.ImageField(upload_to = "photos/", verbose_name = "Photo de profil", blank = True)
    entreprise = models.ForeignKey('Entreprise', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    facturation = models.CharField(max_length = 20, verbose_name = "Numéro de carte bancaire")

#######################################################################################################################

class Entreprise(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    region = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length = 100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Entreprise"
        ordering = ['nom']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

Code for actualites.models :

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from inscription.models import Client, Chef, Entreprise



#######################################################################################################################

class Plat(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField(null = True)
    allergenes = models.TextField(null = True)
    chef = models.ForeignKey('Chef', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de préparation")
    nb_portions = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre de portions disponibles")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = "photos/", blank = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Plat"
        ordering = ['date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titre

#######################################################################################################################

class Commande(models.Model):
    plat = models.ForeignKey('Plat', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    nb_portions = models.IntegerField(verbose_name = "Nombre de portions")
    entreprise = models.ForeignKey('Entreprise', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de commande")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Commande"
        ordering = ['date']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.plat) + " pour " + str(self.entreprise)
```

Comment: No there is no such thing as defining models at project level. Importing from one app to another is the way to go; in your case you probably have a circular import which is preventing them from working. But without code and error messages we can't really help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have edited my question

Comment: You should post code as text in the question, rather than posting links to images. But also you need to show the actual models code. Why for example do you need to import Plat and Commande in inscription? The foreign keys point the other way.

Comment: Sorry I'm not used to Stack Overflow either, I have added the code for the two models files. I deleted the import of Plat and Commande in inscription and it gaves me again the error1 instead of error2

Comment: When you're referencing a model in another app in the FK string you need to use the appname: "inscription.Entreprise", "inscription.Chef".

Comment: That solves the problem, thanks a lot for your kind help ! Have a good day :)